# Error: generic parameter 'Key' could not be inferred when creating a Dictionary

Tags: swift, swift4

I am getting this error with this code (1):

```
let keys = [1, 1]
let values = ["one", "two"]

let dict = Dictionary(zip(keys, values)){$0 + ", " + $1}
```

This code (2) is fine though:

```
let keys = [1, 1]
let values = ["one", "two"]

let dict = Dictionary(zip(keys, values)){$0 + $1}
```

Why generic parameter 'Key' could not be inferred in (1)? (I am aware that I can use *{first, second in first + ", " + second}* instead, and it will work; but I just want to understand what is wrong with *$0 + ", " + $1* comparing to *$0 + $1*)

Comment: Side note: I would avoid using a trailing closure for `Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`, it's a new API and rather unknown, `Dictionary(zip(keys, values)){$0 + $1}` is quite unclear

Comment: Also, String interpolation is really beneficial (over the string concatenation operator `+`) cases like this, involving complex expressions with difficult typechecking complexity.

Comment: What's interesting is: `let dict = Dictionary(zip(keys, values)){ (a, b) in a + ", " + b }` works. I think maybe it is just a compiler bug.

Comment: More strange, `let dict = Dictionary(zip(keys, values)){  $0+", " + $1+""}` also works. It seems the suffix empty string makes `Type Inference` normal.

Answer (score -1):

It appears it cannot determine the type of the key for your dictionary based on the Int array.

You need to explicitly tell it what the type of the key is.

Comment: let dict: [Int: String] = <...> ? Same result.

Comment: Obviously this is the answer but *how* is what people are looking for.